# chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener() not running when the first window is created

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want the window to prompt the user when the window is first created. My code prompts the user if the user creates ANOTHER new window (e.g.: pulling a tab out of the window to create its own window, or clicking on the chrome icon a second time), but not when the very FIRST window is created. Why is this?

Background script:

```
//an array of current open windows.
var windowArray = {};

//when a new window is created, start the creation of a new package.
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(createWindowPackage);


//get current window's id
function getCurrentWinID(callback){
  console.log("getCurrentWinID() called")
  var windId;
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(currentWin){
     windId = currentWin.id;
      //console.log("from getCurrentWinID(), windId = " + windId)
     //*****unique window Id properly getting retrieved here
     callback(windId);
  });  
}

//_______________________________________________________________________________________

//start the creation of a new 'windowPackage' object by prompting the user for a goal. 
function createWindowPackage(){
    var goal = prompt("What is your goal this browsing session?","E.g: To watch Daniel Schiffman's first video.");
  var windId;

  //getting the current window's id
  getCurrentWinID(function(windId){
    var winId = windId.toString();
    //*****unique window id properly received here

    //in the windowArray, have the windId key refer to a new windowPackage object.
    windowArray[winId] = new windowPackage(goal, windId);
    //*****so we've successfully created a new window package with this goal and a unique window Id
  });
}

//_________________________________________________________________________________________
//a window package includes the window id and a tasks[] array
class windowPackage{
    constructor(startTask, winId){
        this.id = winId;//winId is a string right now.
        this.tasks = [startTask];
        this.goal = startTask;
        this.isItOn = 1;
    }
```

Somehow the  but the above code doesn't work for prompting the user when the first new window is created, but this code does work:

```
//an array of current open windows.
var goal;

chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(askGoal);

function askGoal(){
    goal = prompt("What is your goal this browsing session?","E.g: To watch Daniel Schiffman's first video.");
    isItOn = 1;

}
```

Comment: 1) The first window, if I understand the question correctly, is the main browser window which is created before any extension runs (unless you specify the background permission and allow Chrome to run such background extensions). 2) chrome.windows.getCurrent doesn't do what you think, see its description again, so you should simply use the parameter which is passed to onCreated callback, see the documentation, you can simply declare function createWindowPackage({id: winId})

Comment: Adding "background" to "permissions" in manifest.json ended up working, thank you :)